# Trouble ploting a graph using plt.plot

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

I'm trying to visualize my data into a time series graph which shows time in months as my x-axis and value as my y-axis

I have imported my data set and added a new period column and qtr to the data set. I keep getting an error where my plot wont generate. I'm new to python so have a hard time knowing what my errors are.

This is the first five lines of my data set. Th orginal data had only columns up to value so I added QTR and concatenated the year and month together.

```
Measure Name    Year    Month   Value   Qtr period
0   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Jan 1757000.0   Q1  2007-Jan
1   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Feb 2052000.0   Q1  2007-Feb
2   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Mar 2747000.0   Q1  2007-Mar
3   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    Apr 2308000.0   Q2  2007-Apr
4   Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials 2007    May 2289000.0   Q2  2007-May
```

I am using this code to try and visualize my data set. I want the value ($) to be my y axis and period (ie 2007 to be my x axis)

```
plt.plot_date(recycle['period'],recycle['Value'])
plt.xlabel('Time(Months)')
plt.ylabel('Value ($CAD)')
plt.show()
```

I was trying to do a time series analysis where date (period would be at the bottom and value would be on be graphed

This is what shows as my plot 
[Plot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJR6w.png)

Comment: Are you certain that the `recycle` DataFrame object actually has a column with name `'Value'`? Try running `print('Value' in recycle.columns)` (this will print out `True` if the column name exists).

Comment: I did as you suggested and the value column is showing as `false`. I don't understand why it would be 'false' as my data set has a values column and it was imported in. All my other columns state that the column name exists (true) except for `'value'`.

Comment: Then you likely made some error while importing the data.

Comment: Run `print(recycle.columns)` to print the column names and look at it very carefully. Check for example that there are no leading or trailing spaces in the string, and check that there are lowercase/uppercase differences.

Comment: I was able to fix it. I can now plot.. but my graph is still not plotting correctly.